# Schema Validation - s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'

Tags: java, xml, schema

I have a schema and sample XML. The xml is failing schema validation with the following error message. Can any one tell me why? I have checked the sample xml and do not see any 'e="ac'.

EDIT: I meant to say I checked the Types.xsd and I don't see the issue.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/src/main/resources/schemas/Types.xsd; lineNumber: 1300; columnNumber: 6; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'e="ac'.

Comment: The error message refers to the _schema_, not the sample xml, and it tells you precisely where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced

> ?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?

with

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

and it worked.

Comment: We got the same error after after adding one line to our xsd. We added line 172 but the error was reported in line 1158. Seems like a bug in xjc. This fix solved it.

Comment: My line was version="1.0", it has errors in my linux eclipse but no error in my mac eclipse. Not sure why. Exactly the same file.